# Code autocompletion for x86 assembly language

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, masm

Does Visual Studio support code autocompletion for x86 assembly language? I've found autocompletion to be useful when working with high-level programming languages such as Java and C++, and I want to know whether a similar feature is available for assembly language in Visual Studio (for example, typing `m` could provide `mov` as a suggestion, and typing `j` would provide `j1` as a suggestion).

Comment: I find that it's difficult to memorize every single keyword for x86 assembly language, so some kind of autocompletion feature would be very useful (if it existed). Would it be possible to implement a code autocompletion feature for assembly language, at least in theory?

Comment: You don't need to memorize every single instruction or keyword. You will memorize the most basic and useful ones (e.g. `mov`, `add`, `ret`, `jz`, etc) very soon though.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Still, an autocompletion could make it easier to learn each of these basic instructions (along with the purpose of each instruction). It would also be useful if the documentation for each keyword could be displayed on-mouseover, which is a feature of IDEs for some other languages.

Comment: I hope that it will be possible to find further relevant information from this Google search query: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=masm+autocomplete&oq=masm+autocomplete&gs_l=hp.3...15780.17211.1.17429.12.8.0.0.0.3.152.656.7j1.8.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.3.psy-ab.RAl84iDwkvY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42452523,d.dmg&fp=8bb62755c027473d&biw=1366&bih=631

Comment: MASM itself is a console program and has no editor, so no autocomplete in MASM.

Comment: @Anderson - If you cannot learn three character instructions, you shouldn't try writing assembly. Honestly! That's the easy part.

Comment: @BoPersson Learning assembly language instructions is easy enough, but that doesn't entirely defeat the purpose of autocompletion, IMO. I still think using autocompletion would make assembly language easier to learn.

Comment: Autocompletion might make it easier to type, but hardly easier to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the only IDEs that provide some autocompletion for assembly language are those designed especially for assembly language.

**[RADASM](http://radasm.cherrytree.at/)** is one example of such IDE.

Although, the main target of assembly autocompletion are not instructions, (because they are short and easy to be type) but the labels and other identifiers.

In the big assembly projects there can be thousands of labels, so the quick navigation inside this set is really very helpful.

One of most advanced autocompletion engines is implemented in **[Fresh IDE](http://fresh.flatassembler.net)**.

It is my project, but I think I am unbiased in this estimation.

Most of the assembly IDEs uses fixed lists of API labels and sometimes scan the source files in order to make lists of detected labels. They are forced to use such tricks, because as a rule they are universal IDEs that must support several different assemblers and HLL compilers.

Fresh IDE is different - it runs real compilation using FASM assembler in order to collect the set of identifiers, detected by the assembler after the compilation. This way all labels are detected properly, even those generated by macros during the assembling process, together with their values, types and hierarchical structure.

This solution was forced, because FASM has very complex and flexible macro system that makes any other detection mechanism unreliable.

Using fixed API lists is also impossible, because Fresh IDE is not bound to some particular API, but is targeted for programming of applications for several supported OSes and even for OS development.

Comment: Can the Fresh IDE be used with MASM as well as FASM?

Comment: No - unfortunately, the only way to get really good IDE is to integrate it very tight with the target compiler. I am not working with HLLs, but AFAIK, FASM can be used together with C/C++ programs. You can compile to COFF object format and then link with everything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this provides autocomplete, but what about using a REPL for X86?
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read–eval–print_loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)

There is one on GitHub
https://github.com/rfw/ex86

Comment: There's also [RadASM](http://www.oby.ro/rad_asm/), which apparently supports autocompletion.

Comment: How does REPL relate to the question?

Comment: The github link is dead.  An x86 REPL would be useful sometimes.  Maybe there's another question where this answer would be on-topic.